# How to Grant Network Service permission a folder for a network drive

Tags: synology

I am currently want to grant "Network Service" permission to a folder in network drive of a pc workstation as I want to change the mysql data directory from "C-drive" to a Network drive in this case is "Z-Drive".

I am able to change the data directory in a drive within the same pc but when I tried to grant permission to a Network Drive the Z-drive. Somehow windows remove "Network Service" when I click apply.

I have tried changing the mysql data directory from "C-Drive" to "D-Drive" as long the the drive is in local pc, I am able to grant permission for Network Service to the folder.

But when I tried to grant permission to a Network Drive (Synology DS224+) windows 10 remove "Network Service" when I click apply changes

Comment: There is no "Network Service" permission.  Do you mean, you want to grant permission for the "Network Service" user to access that file share?  You can't do that.  You can't share a drive that is being shared with you.  It's up to the file server (that is, the Synology device).  Can't you run your mysql server as a user that has access to that share?

Comment: Do you realize you can run a MySQL server on that Synology device?  They are quite flexible.

Comment: Essentially I want the data directory of my MySQL server to be in the synology device in this case is a Z-drive which is a networked drive. My current drive is about to be full. To change the drive I need to grant permission for MySQL (Log On as "Network Service" refer to Services) to read/write that particular folder.  Have anyone encounter this issue before when "Network Service" is being removed from when I click apply after adding the service to security permission

Comment: Yes, I understand the situation, and I told you why it doesn't work,  You do not own that resource -- it belongs to the Synology file server.  Because of that, you do not have the authority to grant permissions to other users.  That would have to be done on the Synology unit itself.

Comment: I install mySQL docker/container manager on my NAS synology and set up the device accordingly i gave an ip to the NAS device and setup mySQL workbench to have the same ip ad the nas. Note is port use in mysql have to be set in docker i.e. I use 32784 for mysql which port to 3306 as the local port. Also if anyone doing the same ensure that the authentication of the nas device with the use account is root login (this can only be set in terminal of the docker.https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_44548582/article/details/122296842